# GAE: How to build a query where a string begins with a value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

In google engine I have the following query to find me all users with the given firstname.

When I type in 'Mi' It would list me all "Michael" and "Mike"'s in the database.

```
class User(UserMixin, ndb.Model):
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()


 data = User.query(ndb.AND(User.firstname >= name_startsWith, User.firstname <= name_startsWith + u'\ufffd')).fetch(5)
```

I would like to make it invariant so that I can type "mi" and it still outputs the same names.

I tried `lower()` in Python, but this doesn't work with app engine's `StringProperty()`

```
 data = User.query(ndb.AND(User.firstname.lower() >= name_startsWith.lower(), User.firstname.lower() <= name_startsWith.lower() + u'\ufffd')).fetch(5)
```

It throws the error:

> AttributeError: 'StringProperty' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 2):

You can't do searches like that with the datastore API. You can either store an additional lower-case version of the field, or use the full-text search API which is meant for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a computed property:

```
class User(UserMixin, ndb.Model):
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
    name_lower = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.firstname.lower())
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

And then use first name that is returned from your query (which will have correct case).

Answer (score 0):

Store a normalized version of any strings you want to be able to
search this way. Queries in App Engine can only do simple filters on
what's actually in the indexes.

Try something like this

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
    firstname_norm = ndb.StringProperty()

username = "Some Name"
User(firstname = username, firstname_norm = normalizer(username)).put()

data = User.query(ndb.AND(User.firstname_norm >= normalizer(name_startsWith), User.firstname_norm <= normalizer(name_startsWith) + u'\ufffd')).fetch(5)
```

where "normalizer()" is a functStore a normalized version of any strings you want to be able to
search this way. Queries in App Engine can only do simple filters on
what's actually in the indexes.ion that converts mixed-case strings
to an all-lowercase form, then use the same function when constructing
queries. This can be as simple as just calling the string's .lower()
method or as complex as removing all punctuation, converting all runs
of whitespace to single spaces, doing unicode normalization, etc.,
depending on your needs.

```
def normalizer(x):
    return x.lower()
```

Comment: Thanks Nijin, well now I have to write a piece of code that goes through al user objects and creates the firstname_norm field across all of them right? otherwise I won't be able to query it this way.

Comment: @Kave Yes. You need to create firstname_norm.